# Will this server suit to runs IRC server on it?

Tags: irc

Disk Space - 2.5 GB;
Bandwidth - 100 GB; 
Dedicated RAM - 64 MB;
Dedicated IP - 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer? yes- though its very dependant on load. The nice thing about irc is you can always add another server, and the resources you need per user is rather small. While you can't, say run something like freenode, that's perfectly sufficent for a small community server.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a lot of questions lately regarding "will my server handle..." and the most common answer is that it *depends*. You need to factor your number of users, the architecture of the program acting as a server, how it handles resources on the server's hardware...

There was a guy using a commodore 64 as a web server. I don't know if he still has it online (I remember something involving slashdot hitting it once...) but it obviously worked as a web server for awhile...

In the end whether something will work for a server of ZYX specs depends entirely on what you know of your users and how hard they're going to slam it.

Comment: There was once a legend that a kid was running a BBS on a VIC-20 and all the output was *hand typed* in real-time (well, as real-time as 300 baud gets anyway). Now [here's](http://www.magic-1.org/) a real he-man server.

Comment: People run web servers on old Apple Newtons.

Comment: @Wesley And iphones. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how many people are on it at the same time, and how much they're using the server, what server software you're running, and other factors. Assuming you don't have too heavy a load, a server like that might work well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. How many users - depends. BUt IRC is a pure text protocol, and it was around when BIG servers only had 64mb memory. So, for a couple of hundred users it SHOULD be enough, unless the software is running on something like Java / .NET.

Answer (score 0):

The main requirement of an IRC server is a decent internet connection with low latency.  It doesn't actually use that much bandwidth, and an IRC server doesn't use much resources if there aren't large numbers of users, but it does need low latency.

Also be aware that many VPS hosting providers (it sounds like you're going to be using a VPS) don't like you running IRC servers.  So you should double check with your provider first.

In cases where I'm not sure if a VPS will provide enough power to run a certain app I normally just go ahead and try.  I can always upgrade the VPS if it needs more power, or drop it after a month if it's argued the upgrade isn't worth the money the app would make.  VPS systems are so cheap these days that there's no reason not to just give it a go.