# Will this server suit to runs IRC server on it?

Tags: irc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will this server suit to runs IRC server on it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/134261/will-this-server-suit-to-runs-irc-server-on-it)

Disk Space - 2.5 GB;
Bandwidth - 100 GB; 
Dedicated RAM - 64 MB;
Dedicated IP - 1;

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/134261/will-this-server-suit-to-runs-irc-server-on-it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

It will run, but won't run very smooth. Considering your HD is 2.5GB and you only have 64MB of ram I will assume this "server" to be in the vicinity of 12 years old?